# Hide (installed) files from search results in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows

I want to hide or remove an installed file from the search results.

Example:

I installed Photoshop on my system. If I press <kbd>Windows</kbd> key and type "ph", the files which have name starting from "ph" start to appear. But I don't want that because in my office they restricted the use of Photoshop.

Sometimes the administrators come, and I want to hide Photoshop from search results. I've hidden Photoshop in Control Panel » Programs.

Comment: Disable indexing on your computer.  Why don't you just get permission to install Photoshop instead of trying to hide your actions because, they likely already know you installed it, when your computer reported the installation of the program in its logs.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the shortcut and select the `Hidden` attribute in the `General` tab. Please note that they will find it if they look more thoroughly. Administrators tend to have the 'view hidden files and folders' settings turned on. In my opinion it's always better to ask and if they don't want it, don't install it. You probably won't need it for your work. And as a bonus, installing pirated software at work is always a big no-no.